# importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt in pycharm fails due to Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

I am having a problem with importing matplotlib,
seems like I messed up something in the configurations 
(it was working perfectly for two weeks of daily programming)

Trying to import matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

now I am getting:

```
C:\Users\Rami\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/Rami/PycharmProjects/project new/ml1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rami/PycharmProjects/project new/ml1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Rami\CONDA3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Rami\CONDA3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Rami\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Rami\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\Rami\CONDA3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Process finished with exit code 1
```

From the error trace, it seems that it is caused by a failure to import Numpy.

Yes I have changes some stuff in the settings but have no idea what led to this

I am working with Python 3.5

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `numpy` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). It's also clear from the error message that your code fails in the very first line, so no need to include anything else here.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing matplotlib?

Comment: @mmenschig i can not do it for some reason:they are telling me to install it via command line but i am using anaconda anyway

Comment: @desertnaut this is my first time writing a question here, i have taken note of what you said and edit it slightly different although the goal of the code is to write decision trees and numpy is not working for me as well,i will be happy if you can help

Comment: Open conda terminal and issue conda install matplotlib

Comment: @jlandercy thanks i almost forget there is a condo prompt,
unfortunately, it did not work though, "could not find "c/.... "
and this might be the problem because i have been using pycharm for a couple of weeks till i changed some setting yesterday, something with the address

Comment: You can force `conda update matplotlib`, also be sure you are updating the right environment. Open you terminal in PyCharm is it create venc for each project.

Comment: @jlandercy, thanks , sorry didn't work, getting: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ex/ex2 (2).py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
  File "C:\Users\Rami\CONDA3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Rami\CONDA3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Rami\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Rami\AppDat